# IBOutlets in UICollectionView are nil - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When I print the IBOutlets I declared in MyCell class, they come out to be nil.

Methods in ViewController

```
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.seriesCollectionView.register(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    cell.setup()

    return cell
}
```

MyCell class

```
class MTSeriesViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var cellView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var cellImageView: UIImageView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

public func setup() {
    print(cellView)
}

}
```

Is there any other way I should be initializing/registering MyCell class in viewDidLoad of ViewController?

Comment: did you make the Cell UI in interface builder ? if so please show where you register the cell

Comment: self.seriesCollectionView.register(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
**remove this line if your not used separate xib for cell** .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of:

`self.seriesCollectionView.register(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")`

use:

```
self.seriesCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCellXibName", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. So classes are to be registered differently from xibs? Can you please give me a good doc to read about it. I am totally new to swift.

Comment: @AsthaGupta The difference is that you should register a class only when the cell's subviews are created in code. If you use a xib file - register a nib.

Comment: In my case, its throwing Could not load NIB in bundle. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In the xib for your custom cell you need to control-drag from you views onto file's owner and connect them to their IBOutlets.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .xib for you cell you have to make a reference outlet using Control-Drag from your view onto file's owner and connect them.